# Trying to install tor but packages have unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, dependencies, tor

I have tried uninstalling with purge and reinstalling with `apt-get` but it seems like I have something that wont let me install tor. Here is the message it gives

```
ROOTUSER :~# apt-get install tor
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libc6-dev : Breaks: libgcc-8-dev (< 8.4.0-2~) but 8.2.0-9 is to be installed
libgirepository-1.0-1 : Breaks: libgjs0g (< 1.58.1-2~) but 1.52.4-1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

how do I locate

> libc6-dev : Breaks: libgcc-8-dev (< 8.4.0-2~) but 8.2.0-9 is to be
> installed  libgirepository-1.0-1 : Breaks: libgjs0g (< 1.58.1-2~) but
> 1.52.4-1

and fix it so that installation goes smoothly?
thanks!

Comment: This usually occurs when you have 1) Manually installed wrong-release or wrong-version packages, or 2) Unwisely added wrong-version or non-Ubuntu sources that provide packages incompatible with your system. In both cases, the solution is to uninstall the conflicting packages and remove the unwisely-added source.

Comment: It can happen with bad package management in general: 3) not keeping up with updates; 4) refusing and rolling back updates; 5) not running `apt update` before other `apt` commands; 6) excessive/improper use of PPA... etc... | Edit your question with the outputs of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.  Please also confirm the version and flavor of Ubuntu you are using.